# How to create AuthProvider for React Authentication [Infinite loop problem]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm writing React 18 application and i've stuck on authentication. I would like to create fancy context to store authorized user data and reuse it on many places.

My problem is: Infinite loop / calling /session endpoint which returns 403

Could you take a look at my code and help me investigate where the real problem is?

All custom hooks are simple fetchers with TanStackQuery. useLogout is disabled on default

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
    const { authStatus } = useSession();
    const { isSuccess, data, isLoading } = useGetUser(
        authStatus === "authorized",
    );
    const [user, setUser] = useState<AuthUser | undefined>(undefined);
    const { mutate } = useLogin();
    const { refetch } = useLogout();

    const login = useCallback(
        (payload: UserCredentials) => {
            mutate(payload);
        },
        [mutate],
    );

    const logout = useCallback(() => {
        refetch();
    }, [refetch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isSuccess) return;
        console.log(data, "useEffectData");
        setUser(data?.data);
    }, [data, isSuccess]);

    const value = useMemo(
        () => ({
            user,
            login,
            logout,
            isLoading,
            authStatus,
        }),
        [authStatus, isLoading, login, logout, user],
    );

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
    const { authStatus } = useAuth();

    if (authStatus === "loading") return <div>App is loading ...</div>;

    if (authStatus === "authorized") {
        return children ? <>{children}</> : <Outlet />;
    }
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```